# Syntax error: "(" unexpected when running Docker container

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, sh, minecraft

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Setup Inst
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER test
LABEL maintainer="test"

RUN mkdir /srv/papermc
WORKDIR /srv/papermc

# Install OpenJDK-17
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jre-headless && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get install -y screen && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get clean;

# Fix certificate issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;

# Setup JAVA_HOME -- useful for docker commandline
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

# Download PAPERMINECRAFT
RUN wget https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.19.3/builds/363/downloads/paper-1.19.3-363.jar

# STOP
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

# ENV
ENV TYPE=VANILLA VERSION=1.19.3 EULA="" UID=1000 GID=1000 RCON_PASSWORD=paper

# Prepare RUN
EXPOSE 25565 25575
VOLUME /srv/papermc
RUN echo "screen -AmdS minecraft java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /srv/mcvanilla/paper-1.19.2-220.jar nogui" > start
RUN chmod -R 775 /srv/papermc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD start
HEALTHCHECK none
```

It is building without errors, but if I try to start the container, I get the following error:

```
Successfully tagged papermc:latest
root@docker3:~# docker run papermc
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I was expecting a Java error because of not accepting the EULA, but not this one. What could be wrong?

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/shell-script-fails-syntax-error-unexpected) may be helpful. You might need to add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line in your `start` script. Or try running it with `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Usually this message means you're running a script written with bash-only syntax like `>()` with sh, which doesn't support those extensions. There are none of those constructs shown here, but for all I know papermc itself starts a shell.

Comment: @KsBs, btw, using `screen` inside a Docker container is generally a bad idea, and completely unnecessary. Docker itself can take care of running processes detached from the terminal, storing logs for later retrieval, etc. The normal/conventional way to run a JVM in Docker is just to have Docker itself run that JVM, without `screen` or `tmux` or anything else in between.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` setup is wrong.  You should simplify the end of the file to

```bash
# ...do the installation steps...
ENV TYPE=VANILLA VERSION=1.19.3 EULA="" UID=1000 GID=1000 RCON_PASSWORD=paper
CMD java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /srv/mcvanilla/paper-1.19.2-220.jar nogui
```

and then `docker run papermc` will start the server without requiring you to log in, start a screen session, or anything else.

As @CharlesDuffy hints in a comment, if you're just wrapping a single process, Docker and Screen have some similarities and it's unusual to use Screen in a container.  You can view the `docker logs` of the container and, in the unusual event you need to interact with the process's stdin, `docker attach` to it.

What's actually happening in your case deals with the way string-form `CMD` is converted to an actual command-word array and then combined with `ENTRYPOINT`.  The [documentation on Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) has details on these mechanics.  As you've written it, the single command the container runs is

```bash
/bin/sh /bin/sh -c 'start'
```

which in turn causes the shell to try to execute the `/bin/sh` binary as a shell script, passing it arguments `-c` and `start` as the positional variables `$1` and `$2`.  When `/bin/sh` is an ELF binary and not itself a shell script, you get a parse error like this.